# Using tags in function overloading

Tags: c++, generic-programming

Why is method test in X ambiguous, and how can this be fixed?

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

template<typename T>
struct I { void test(T){} };
struct X : public I<A>, I<B> {};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    X x;
    x.test(A());
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error:

```
In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
error: request for member ‘test’ is ambiguous
error: candidates are: void I<T>::test(T) [with T = B]
error:                 void I<T>::test(T) [with T = A]
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that the current code is ambiguous and doesn't compile, that this code fixes the ambiguity but you don't like the style, what?

Comment: @Useless, I have elaborated the question a bit to clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`test` is ambiguous because it is a member of two base classes of `X`. While not both functions match, the *name* matches.

Fix with an explicit forward:

```
struct X : public I<A>, I<B> {
    template <typename T>
    void test(T t) { I<T>::test(t); }
};
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, this is the way to go. Much more user-friendly than my answer.

Comment: @ltn100: Thanks, even though I like PlasmaHH's `using` even better. :-)

Comment: It's slightly more readable, but you would have to add a new using statement for every new base class. I'm not an advocate of multiple inheritance, but it seems that is the functionality that the OP is after.

Answer (score 3):

Use using:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

template<typename T>
struct I { void test(T){} };
struct X : public I<A>, I<B> 
{
    using I<A>::test;
    using I<B>::test;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    X x;
    x.test(A());
    return 0;
}
```

The gcc error `request for member 'test' is ambiguous` is not really the best here, we can see better what is meant with the error of clang: `member 'test' found in multiple base classes of different types`

Comment: thiton's forwarding approach means you write 10 forwarding functions, instead of 100 using statements.

Comment: @Useless: The OP question is underspecified to chose which solution is really better; if the real problem requires to forward more complex/unusual types, you need to be much more careful and at least use what C++11 calls "perfect forwarding". But even then, in the case the overloads take function pointers, and you pass an overloaded function to the test function, forwarding won't help you there to have the overload matching the function parameter chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Because `X` multiply inherits from `I<A>` and `I<B>`, the call to `test()` is ambiguous. You can do this to explicitly declare which parent you are referring to:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

template<typename T>
struct I { void test(T){} };
struct X : public I<A>, I<B> {};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    X x;
    x.I<A>::test(A());
    return 0;
}
```